# SQL JOIN HOW TO correct make sql query

Tags: sql, join, group-by, pivot

I hawe two tables

1. match_id,color, date etc.(name: matches)
2. match_id, player_id. etc (namepalyer_matches)

Second table can have 10 players with the same match_id.

I want to make 1 sql query to get table like

```
match_id, player_id_1,player_id_2,player_id_3,etc,color,date
```

I try use:

```
SELECT M.*, PM.player_id 
from matches M 
join player_matches P on M.match_id = P.match_id
```

But receive just 1 player_id. how can i do my right sql query to achieve correct result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    match_id,
    max(case when pm.rn = 1 then pm.player_id end) player_id_01,
    max(case when pm.rn = 2 then pm.player_id end) player_id_02,
    ...
    max(case when pm.rn = 10 then pm.player_id end) player_id_10,
    m.color,
    m.date
from matches m
inner join (
    select pm.*, row_number() over(partition by match_id order by player_id) rn 
    from player_matches pm
) pm on pm.match_id = m.match_id
group by m.match_id, m.color, m.date
```

This generates one record per match, with a maximum of 10 players in columns, ordered by player id.